# What renders first when starting the angular2 app, html or .ts file?

Tags: javascript, angular

Can anyone explain what happens when we open a URL of a single page application built in angular?

Does the initial app.component.ts execute first (constructor and ngOnInit) and then the app.component.html renders or is it the other way around. Also what If I have some @Inputs() defined and the inputs provide the .ts file with some data from the app.component.html file, what happens in such cases where the app.component.ts has to wait for the input property values?

Can anyone give a good link or explain this process in a few lines (not going too deep with it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, every component has a template (HTML), styles (CSS) and the body (the TypeScript class). Typescript class is the actual component.

```
@Component({
  template: `
    <div>
      <h4>{{data.headline}}</h4> 
      {{data.body}}
    </div>
  `
})
export class MyComponent{
  @Input() data: any;

}
```

If you want to, you can specify the template in a separate file (makes sense for when you have more than a couple of lines of HTML) - that does not change anything.

First, the component gets instantiated as a class. Then the component lifecycle starts - you  can read more about it in the [official documentation](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks).

The class is what renders the template, and in the lifecycle documentation you can see that view is created after certain hooks have been run - giving you a chance to get the `@Input`s and otherwise set up data for the view.

Comment: "giving you a chance to get the @Inputs and otherwise set up data for the view." This was bothering me, tnx!